# How to return array from a function?

Tags: php, arrays, function, return

This function was okay for yesterday, I have no idea why it can't return array value now.

I tried to dump out the value at Xxxx...the result was perfect...but when I dump before return $downlinesArray(last return) I only get the first array[0] value...which is passing from another function...I have no idea why...can anyone point it out?

And after it returns the array, I get nothing from another side. Which is calling this function and get array value.

```
function findEntireGroupDownlinesMemberID($downlinesArray, $index)
{
    $downlineDB = $this->getDistributorInformation($downlinesArray[$index]);
    if ($downlineDB) {
Xxxx
        if ($downlineDB->getLeftPositionDistCode()) {
            array_push($downlinesArray, $downlineDB->getLeftPositionDistCode());
        }

        if ($downlineDB->getRightPositionDistCode()) {
            array_push($downlinesArray, $downlineDB->getRightPositionDistCode());
        }
        $index++;
        return $this->findEntireGroupDownlinesMemberID($downlinesArray, $index);
    }
    return $downlinesArray;
}
```

Comment: You need to pass the array by reference `function findEntireGroupDownlineMemberID(&$downlinesArray, $index) {`. Have a look at [Passing by Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

Comment: Hi Cyclone, I tried, but shows nth. It gave me 500 internal server error

Answer (score 0):

If you need to modify the original `$downlinesArray` array, you need to pass it to your function [by its reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php).
Also you get an error because your code never reaches the second return statement. Check the snippet:

```
{
    if ($downlineDB) {  //if this is true, the 2nd return statement will never get executed.
    Xxxx
        if ($downlineDB->getLeftPositionDistCode()) {
            array_push($downlinesArray, $downlineDB->getLeftPositionDistCode());
        }

        if ($downlineDB->getRightPositionDistCode()) {
            array_push($downlinesArray, $downlineDB->getRightPositionDistCode());
        }
         $index++;
         return $this->findEntireGroupDownlinesMemberID($downlinesArray, $index);  //function exits here
    }
    return $downlinesArray;
}
```

And when `$downlineDB` evaluates to be false, all you get is the first array value `array[0]` as expected.

Comment: Hi Niket, yeah. That is actually I want it. It will loop until no downline, then return whole array back.